# Issues in sorting using map function due to url size exceeding in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, solr6

I have a data stored with my preferred colour in DB as : red,yellow,black..... suppose 20 colours, Now whenever I search using SOLR I want my results to be boosted on basis of my preferred colour?   how can we do this....
I tried map function of SOLR but for so many preferred colours my solr url length increases considerably.  is there any easier way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the value into separate tokens or pre-process it to a multi valued field, then use a boost query to boost any results that match your query.

You can use a PatternTokenizer to split the field into separate tokens:

```
 <fieldType name="text_color" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="," />
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>

<field name="color" type="text_color" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

.. and the boost it in your query, using (e)dismax:

```
 &bq=color:red^10
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just need to add some thing I have made the field as a multivalued field i.e now i have colors as multivalued. In this case I have a dependency for example I want to boost my results with cases for example only if my title is an exact phrase as **"RED APPLES"** and color is red than only provide the boost is it possible using AND in bq

Comment: Yes. The boost query is a regular query, so `field:"RED APPLES" AND color:red` should work.